# Jquery count from 0 to value from api

Tags: jquery

I have a strange problem for me. 
On my web, I show to user `outputed` energy data with the animated number and count from zero to value from my `api`. Problem is, when I "hard coded" numbers, counting works, but if I try to count number from API, they don't count. Here is `plunker` for a better explanation.

```js
//get zahtjev za analytics
function auto_load() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://testtest/live-stats",
    cache: false,
    success: function loadCounter(data) {
      $("#proizvedeno").text(data.total_energy_output.toFixed(2)); //here I set data to ID to show value in html
      $("#potroseno").text(data.total_energy_consumed.toFixed(2));
    }

  });
  
  /* here is how response from servers look
  
 total_energy_consumed:2619.8083750057
 total_energy_output:2625.9020281394
  
*/
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  auto_load(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready

});

//Refresh auto_load() function after 30000 milliseconds
setInterval(auto_load, 60000);




$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 6000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  //Animated Progress
  $('.progress-bar').bind('inview', function(event, visible, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
    if (visible) {
      $(this).css('width', $(this).data('width') + '%');
      $(this).unbind('inview');
    }
  });

  //Animated Number
  $.fn.animateNumbers = function(stop, commas, duration, ease) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var start = parseInt($this.text().replace(/,/g, ""));
      commas = (commas === undefined) ? true : commas;
      $({
        value: start
      }).animate({
        value: stop
      }, {
        duration: duration == undefined ? 1000 : duration,
        easing: ease == undefined ? "swing" : ease,
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.value));
          if (commas) {
            $this.text($this.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
          }
        },
        complete: function() {
          if (parseInt($this.text()) !== stop) {
            $this.text(stop);
            if (commas) {
              $this.text($this.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  };

  $('.animated-number').bind('inview', function(event, visible, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (visible) {
      $this.animateNumbers($this.data('digit'), false, $this.data('duration'));
      $this.unbind('inview');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic);

/*************************
*******Typography******
**************************/
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #64686d;
  line-height: 26px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #272727;
}
#animated-number {
  padding: 100px 0 70px;
  background: #132125 url(../images/animated-number/bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}
#animated-number h1,
#animated-number h2,
#animated-number h3,
#animated-number h4 {
  color: #fff;
}
#animated-number strong {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.animated-number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 140px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.section-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.section-header .section-title {
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #272727;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}
.section-header .section-title:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.section-header .section-title:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #C1C1C1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
      <div class="animated-number"><span class="count">560506</span></div>
      <strong>Total energy output in kWh <p style="color: red">
      (this is examle with hard coded number)
      </p></strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      <div id="potroseno" class="animated-number"><span class="count"></span></div>
      <strong>Total energy consumed in kWh</strong>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr2nzc0a/)

Comment: That's a lot of off-site code you want us to go debug for you.  Where specifically is the problem?  Where are you setting a value that isn't working?  When you debug, what is that runtime value?

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: @David I show exactly what not work, and showed an example of how it works and how not work? If I knew the answer I would not even ask here. I'm sorry that my English is not a native language, so that makes it a problem for you to understand, and that's why you give me negative points. Thank you

Comment: @Barmar 99% of question here on stackoverflow is explaned on plunker or jsfiddle. I don't get what's problem with this?

Comment: @Arter That's why Stack Snippets were created last year, so you could put the code here instead.

Comment: @Arter: Sorry, but you seem to be misunderstanding how Stack Overflow works.  You are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help  In particular, this community asks that relevant code be shown in the question itself.  Off-site working examples are a good way to accompany the question, but are not a *substitute* for the question.  Additionally, you are expected to perform at least *some* debugging to narrow down the problem.  It's unlikely that any users here will debug your entire program for you.  You are expected to specify where the problem is occurring.

Comment: @David is this now ok?

Comment: @Barmar i make snippets

Comment: @Arter: It's certainly a step in the right direction.  Now, where in all of this code is this "counting" taking place?  Where do you replace a working hard-coded value with a non-working dynamic one?  Where does that dynamic value come from and what is it at runtime?  Are there any errors in the browser console when you test your code?

Comment: @david in comment everything write. Please read before you ask. Why is important if I have any error in console? I simply write and show how my response looks, and explain when they don't count and when they count. How Yamen Nassif understand and give me answer? Because he read my question. If you read it, then you would understand that I did not seek any debuging, I did everything completely and everything is in code, and I show server response. But it is easiest to give a negative point and treat frustration on someone who asks for help. Thank you and goodbye

Comment: @Arter: I'm glad someone debugged your code for you and was able to help you, but understand that you got lucky on that.  In the future you may want to spend less time complaining about votes and language barriers and more time debugging and presenting the problem to be solved.  Everybody here read your question, nobody here had a problem understanding your English.  It was simply a bad question, and the community responded as such.  You are still encouraged to review the materials here: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153028/discussion-between-arter-and-david).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading the whole page with JS before adding the number so actually the JS is working and counting but only to 0. The solution is to call the API first then call your JS.